# Can't create a new thread (errno 12)

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I have hosted my mysql database on Amazon RDS. Some time I am getting error "Can't create a new thread (errno 12); if you are not out of available memory, you can consult the manual for a possible OS-dependent bug". I have "db.m3.xlarge" (15Gib memory, 30GB space) instance on RDS, and set value for "max_connections" is 1263, and "query_cache_size" is 1048576. So, I don't understand which parameter I should have to configure. Can someone explain what to do in this situation.